# Отрисовка кадров в phaser.js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

```js
function update() {
  if (roulette.circle.previousCircle) {
    roulette.circle.previousCircle.destroy()
  }

  if (roulette.circle.previousLever) {
    roulette.circle.previousLever.destroy();
  }

  if (roulette.circle.currentStep === 100 && run) {
    ball.run = true;
  }

  let circle = this.add.image(108, 110, `circle${roulette.circle.currentStep}`).setOrigin(0, 0).setScale(0.7);
  let lever = this.add.image(200, 150, `lever${roulette.lever.currentStep}`).setOrigin(0, 0).setScale(0.7);

  roulette.circle.method();
  roulette.lever.method();
  roulette.circle.previousCircle = circle;
  roulette.circle.previousLever = lever;
}
```

В **Phaser.js** есть функция **update**, которая и отвечает за все изменения. Как ограничить скорость её выполнения? Допустим, мне надо, чтобы она срабатывала в 2 раза реже

Comment: А зачем вам это если не секрет?

Comment: @ThisMan, делаю рулетку. На "колесо" приходится 359 фотографий, в `update` они постоянно меняются, в итоге получается, что рулетка быстро крутиться + бывают проблемы с производительностью

Comment: `update` нужно вызвать столько раз, сколько он вызывается. Можно код `update`? Тут скорее всего нужно оптимизировать именно внутренности, а не уменьшать частоту кударов/тиков игрового движка

Comment: @ThisMan, поправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией декоратором:

```js
    function wrap(fn, howOften) {
        let count = 0;
        let lastRes;
        return function () {
            if (count % howOften === 0) {
                lastRes = fn.apply(this, arguments);
            }
            count++;
            return lastRes;
        }
    }

Использование:

    const update = wrap(phaser.update.bind(phaser), 2);
```

Comment: Да, способ неплох. Но думал есть какой-нибудь "фазерский" способ